# TSQL create a stored procedure using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure(drop a procedure and remake it with new data) in my .net project. When I run the same query in Database "Create New Query" it works fine, but when I try to run it in c#, it gives me an error.

[image: This is the successful query completed when i run it on Database]

```
private void makeprocedure()
            {
                string sqlProcedureCreate = @"
    IF(OBJECT_ID('usp_HourData') IS NOT NULL)
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_HourData;
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_HourData
    AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT Employee.[First Name] + ' ' + Employee.[Last Name] AS 'Name',
     sum(Time.[Total Hours]) AS 'Total Hours'
     , FORMAT(Time.[Time in], 'd', 'en-gb') AS 'Worked On'
     FROM Employee
     inner join Time on
     Employee.ID ='" + getID() + "' and Time.EmployeeIdFK = '" + getID()
     + "' WHERE Time.[Time in] between '" + CalendarStart.SelectedDate + "' and '" + CalendarEnd.SelectedDate
     + @"'GROUP BY FORMAT(Time.[Time in], 'd', 'en-gb') ,Employee.[First Name] + ' ' +Employee.[Last Name];
     END     
     ";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlProcedureCreate, con))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //I tried command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        con.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Compiler says error is on this line
                        con.Close();
                }
            }
```

The error is near "GO" and "CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE" must go first.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  Class=15
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  HResult=-2146232060
  LineNumber=4
  Message=Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
  Number=102
  Procedure=""
  Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at WebApplication2.Manager.makeprocedure() in D:\Users\Albin\MyClockIn\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Manager.aspx.cs:line 209
       at WebApplication2.Manager.ButtonSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Users\Albin\MyClockIn\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Manager.aspx.cs:line 161
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

How would I go about this error?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say you can't do multiple SQL commands in Visual Studio.  I don't know for sure (I always do it in SSMS), but that's what the error would seem to indicate.

Comment: what is the reason why you need to do it from C# ? Normally this is not how DB Objects are created.

Comment: it should be `command.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: @Rahul - `ExceuteNonQuery` is the proper command for this.  `ExecuteReader` is to return a result set via a `SqlDataReader`. OP is trying to create a stored procedure in the database, not retrieve data.

Comment: remove Go and terminate statement with ;..Go is only for ssms and it acts as a batch seperator

Comment: @Tim, that way may be since it won't fetch resultset but still `ExceuteNonQuery` shouldn't be a proper option. I would rather go for using `ExecuteScalar()` and not nonquery.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, shouldn't be an issue since at C# end it's just a string and ultimately will be executed by SQL Server DB engine which understands `GO` very well.

Comment: @Rahul - ExectueScalar is probably the better choice - though the whole approach is questionable, IMO.

Comment: @Tim, Yes, have never seen someone creating SP using application code though :)

Comment: You might want to check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxsa8hkf(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because I am making a chart control and so the data always changes according to different inputs. So making a procedure seems to get all the correct data loaded into the chart. I tried ExecuteScalar() and took out GO and none works. Thanks guys

Comment: are you re-creating this SP with different SQL everytime there is a change in INPUT parameters ?

Comment: That was the original plan, but the execution itself doesnt work. However, it works when i just put it in the database. Is there any solution using ALTER rather than DROP??

Comment: Your approach to create a stored procedure is debatable. But if you still want to get this working, you should issue the statement to drop the sp if it exists AND the one to create the new sp as two separate commands from the C# side. 

A better approach might be to design a sp which takes a well defined set of input parameters and the C# code invoking it with the appropriate set of parameters.

Comment: I have tried what you said. It still gives me an error. I am actually new to databases.

Comment: @AlbinVinoy PLEASE dont do this. SQL / C# is not meant to be used this way. If you can properly write down your requirements someone will give you a correct solution. What you are doing is a great example of how **NOT** to do it.

Comment: @objectNotFound Sorry I am extremely new to Database programming. I feel ashamed asking this question before doing further research on SP. After everyone saying this is not the way to go I am reading more about SP. I have been using the SP wrong, and I think from what I am reading I have to make a procedure and pass parameters into the procedure and not create a procedure itself. I want to figure this project alone so I can learn something new. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: No problem. Nothing to be ashamed of. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the answer to your question but just an advice about your programming style. These are bad things in your code:

1. You are concatenating query string. You should use parameters.
2. You are creating a procedure where query contains data not the parameters. Stored procedure should contain query with parameters and you should pass data to it.

Stored procedures are not supposed to be dropped and recreated each time you access them. I can clearly see you can achieve the same result by just using the select statement. If you are creating stored procedures there must be some data to pass otherwise there is no point in making a stored procedure.

Enough theory, Let's see things in action:

**Here is your MakeProcedure (please rename this) Function:**

```
//Rename this function to some useful name
private void makeprocedure()
{
    string query = @" SELECT Employee.[First Name] + ' ' + Employee.[Last Name] AS 'Name',
sum(Time.[Total Hours]) AS 'Total Hours'
, FORMAT(Time.[Time in], 'd', 'en-gb') AS 'Worked On'
FROM Employee
inner join Time on
Employee.ID = @EmpId and Time.EmployeeIdFK = @EmpId WHERE Time.[Time in] 
between @StartDate and @EndDate GROUP BY FORMAT(Time.[Time in], 'd', 'en-gb'),
Employee.[First Name] + ' ' +Employee.[Last Name];";


    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", getID());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", CalendarStart.SelectedDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", CalendarEnd.SelectedDate);
        con.Open();
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //do something with data in the reader.
        con.Close();
    }
}
```